# Grepping more than exact input and have related inputs echoed

Tags: php, html, grep, echo

I'm looking to improve my script but I don't know where or how to start.

So, my overall goal is to use my PHP script to grep through a folder with txt files, and for whatever search I put in it will echo that and everything after on that one line in the txt file.

So, I submit a request through the html file for whatever term I searched, lets say it was "*test*", the request is processed through my PHP file below and the directory **files** is checked for the search term "*test*" and the files directory has multiple txt files with "*test*" in many variations, for example:

```
test1
test example
test3945
```

I want to improve this script by having it echo the whole line of whatever the search term may have been, so if I searched just "*test*", it would have not only brought up "*test1*" , "*test*" , "*test3945*" , but would have also included the rest of the text on the same line for "*test* *example*".

I've included UTF-8 character support in my code from my original, just incase that may be the issue why I'm getting exact listings instead of my overall goal.

Here is my HTML file:

```
<form method="POST" action="search.php" class="search" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="query" maxlength=75 minlength=3 
placeholder="enter data" required>
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</input>
</form>
```

Here is my PHP file: ( search.php )

```
header("content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
echo "<pre>";
system('grep -hwir ' . escapeshellarg($_POST['query']) . 
'*files/*.txt');
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `-w` option to grep.

> -w, --word-regexp         force PATTERN to match only whole words

```
$ grep -hir test files/*.txt
test1
test example
test3945
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read things right, you want a search term followed by the rest of the line.  You might want to use sed for simple search/replace.

`sed -n "s/.*test/test/p" inputfile > outputfile`

That says:

- `sed -n`: only print to outputfile if instructed to
- `s/.*test/test/p`: delete everything before `test` in lines containing `test` with `test` and `p` print.

You can script this with an arbitrary search term by replacing `test` with a shell variable.